# Excel vba: Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a `Client` class. Inside that class there is an array `losses`. First I create and populate with clients a `clientsColl` array. Then for each client in that array I populate its `losses` array.

Then I try to print into debug a first element of `losses` for each client. However, it doesnt work and `Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object` error appears.

And the same time if I just try to display a first element of `losses` for *the first* client, without any cycle, it works fine:

```
Dim clientsColl() As Client
clientsColl = getClients(dataWorkbook)

Dim clientCopy As Variant    

Debug.Print "first: " & clientsColl(1).getLosses(1) 'works fine
For Each clientCopy In clientsColl
    Debug.Print "in for each: " & clientCopy.getLosses(1) 'error here
Next
```

In `Client` class:

```
Public Property Get getLosses()
    getLosses = losses
End Property

Private losses() As Double
```

How the `losses` array is populated:

```
Public Sub calculateFinancialResult()
    ReDim losses(1 To simulationCount)
    ReDim profits(1 To simulationCount)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To simulationCount
        If outcomes(i) = 1 Then
            losses(i) = totalLoss
            ...
        Else
            ...
        End If
    Next
 End Sub
```

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

**EDIT:** more of the main sub:

```
For Each clientCopy In clientsColl
        clientCopy.setSimulationCount = globals("SIMULATION_COUNT")
        ...
        clientCopy.calculateFinancialResult
        ...
Next
```

**EDIT:**

At the same time a simple `for` cycle works fine:

```
Debug.Print "first: " & clientsColl(1).getLosses(1)
For tempCount = LBound(clientsColl) To UBound(clientsColl)
    Debug.Print "in for each: " & _
                clientsColl(tempCount).getLosses(1)
Next
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it and seeing what the upper bound of each array is? Do you populate losses in the initialise event of Client?

Comment: @Harassed Dad The `losses` is populated a couple lines before the cycle. The thing is, the `Debug` only prints `first: 0`. Which means, that at least for the first client the first element of the array exists. At the same time *no* debug print from `for each` cycle appears - while we know for sure that at least for one client it should have appeared.

Comment: "The losses is populated a couple lines before the cycle."  Are you sure it is actually populating all clients? If there's an error there it would explain it. F8 is your friend here.

Comment: Try to declare `clientCopy` as `Client`. You can iterate `for each` not only with `Variants`. It's also solves the problem.

Comment: @Harassed Dad I tried f8 and it breaks right on the first `getLosses` call. And yes, I'm sure it populates all the array - I debug printed it for each client.

Comment: @CommonSense I get a `For Each control variable on arrays must be Variant` error.

Comment: Oh, I see. Anyway, you can't achieve what you want as is with such types.Use a `collection` of clients instead and after that apply my previous suggestion (or just don't use `for each`). Is there any idea behind arrays?

Comment: @CommonSense I can't use a `Collection` because it greatly decreases a performance and free memory. I must use arrays. And I don't understand why I can't. Isn't it allowed to store object of custom classes in arrays and access them? If so, why should there be an error?

Comment: Because it's similar to early/late binding problem, `vba` just doesn't know what expect from `clientCopy.getLosses(1)`, where both of variables (`clientCopy` and `getLosses`) are `Variants`. If you still want to execute such a loop try this statement (`Debug.Print clientCopy.getLosses()(1)`) in your loop (or store result of `clientCopy.getLosses()` somewhere inside).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getLosses` property doesn't take an argument so your syntax is actually wrong, even though VBA can cope with it when early bound. You should be using:

```
Debug.Print "first: " & clientsColl(1).getLosses()(1) 'works fine
For Each clientCopy In clientsColl
    Debug.Print "in for each: " & clientCopy.getLosses()(1) 'error here
Next
```

Comment: The same happens if `getLosses` is a *field* though, as opposed to a property (i.e. `Public getLosses As Variant`). And the solution is also the same, to add `()`, which now looks weird because it's not a method or property call.

Answer (score 5):

To conclude what was said in comments:

Your problem (error 451) often occures when you trying to compound properties.
To represent this case we can use any structure of *any object with properties*.

Let's emulate it with array of collections:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim Col As Collection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    ReDim Arr(1 To 10)

    For i = 1 To 10
        Set Col = New Collection
        For j = 1 To 10
            Call Col.Add(j)
        Next

        Set Arr(i) = Col
    Next

    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print Arr(1).Item(1)
    Debug.Print Arr(1).Item()(1)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Your problem stems from the fact that you're treating your properties as attributes. On not-so-compounded (or when your array is declared explicitly as array of class instances) level it works due to early binding. But when things start to get more complex - it's fail, since your property just another function.

Hence, to achieve what you want, you should call it explicitly with another pair of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this problem when I create my customize array class using compound properties.

I solved it by adding class statment for return value in `Property Get` code. Just as what @Rory said.

You could try `Public Property Get getLosses() As Double`  in the `Client` class.