# Getting Object member from dictionary in vba

Tags: vba, class, dictionary, member, variant

I have a class with a member that is an array of double

```
'cls_Person
Public Name as String
Public InAMeeting as Variant
'InAMeeting: Type: Array of Double.
'Sometimes with dimensions of 1 to 8, sometimes of 1 to 10.
```

I fill my class in a loop and then fill them into a global dictionary with a string as the key.

My problem comes when I try to access the InAMeeting member directly from the dictionary:

```
'g_dict_People is a globally defined dictionary.
'KeyPerson is a unique key in the dictionary matching a filled object of type cls_Person
Dim Bravo as Double
Bravo = g_dict_People(KeyPerson).InAMeeting(3)
```

results in error:
Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object (Error 451)

But if I first create a copy of the object from the dictionary then it works:

```
Dim Bravo as Double
Set temp_cls_Person = g_dict_People(KeyPerson)
Bravo = temp_cls_Person.InAMeeting(3)
```

I can access the Name member directly - this works:

```
Dim Alpha as string
Alpha = g_dict_People(KeyPerson).Name
```

Why the difference? Is it to do with the way that I declared the InAMeeting member in the class definition? Is there any way to directly access an object's members when they are of type array?

Sorry I haven't detailed a minimal working example - the code is spread out across multiple modules and classes.

Comment: Would you please show the code that creates the array and fills in `InAMeeting`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test your code since we don't have an MCVE, but the following code works for me.  Modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47532599/2877364).  TIL yet another use case for `()`! 
 Try:

```
Bravo = g_dict_People(KeyPerson).InAMeeting()(3)
                          ' extra parens!  ^^
```

`InAMeeting` is apparently implemented as a property, i.e., a function that you have to call to get the array you want to index into.  The extra `()` make that call.

My test case:

**Class1.cls**

```
Public v As Variant
```

**ThisDocument.bas**

```
Public Sub foo()
    Dim v As Variant
    v = Array(1#, 2#, 3#, 4#, 5#)    ' Assuming you're doing something like this

    Dim o As Class1          ' Put the variant array in the object
    Set o = New Class1
    o.v = v

    Dim c As Collection      ' Put the object in the collection
    Set c = New Collection
    c.Add o, "key"

    On Error Resume Next

    Err.Clear
    Debug.Print "Direct"
    Debug.Print v(3)         ' Works OK
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description

    Err.Clear
    Debug.Print "From collection with ()"
    Debug.Print c("key").v()(3)             ' <== Your use case - works OK
    '        Extra parens ^^
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description

    ' Reproducing the problem

    Err.Clear
    Debug.Print "From collection"
    Debug.Print c("key").v(3)      ' <== Bombs --- I think this is analogous to your use case
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description

    Err.Clear
    Dim o1 As Object
    Set o1 = c("key")
    Debug.Print "Intermediate object"
    Debug.Print o1.v(3)         ' Trying what you tried, but it didn't work for me.
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description

    ' Another thing that works

    Err.Clear
    Debug.Print "Intermediate object with ()"
    Debug.Print o1.v()(3)               ' <== This works
    '   Those extra ^^ parens
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a helpful use case to follow.

Comment: Thank you - This solves the problem. And I learned something new!