# VBA how to access dictionary Keys elements directly

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

## context

In VBA you can create and fill a dictionary like:

```vb
    Dim oDict As Object
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    oDict("key 1") = "value 1"
    oDict("key 2") = "value 2"
    oDict("key 3") = "value 3"
```

With the [Keys method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/keys-method) you can get the keys as array:

> Returns an array containing all existing keys in a Dictionary object.

```vb
    Dim aKeys() As Variant
    aKeys = oDict.Keys
    Debug.Print VarType(aKeys)       ' prints "8204"
    Debug.Print VarType(oDict.Keys)  ' prints "8204"
```

## the problem

But when I access one of the keys directly it gives this cryptic error message:

```vb
    Debug.Print aKeys(2)       ' prints "key 3"
    Debug.Print oDict.Keys(2)  ' Run-time error '451':
                               ' Property let procedure not defined 
                               ' and property get procedure did not 
                               ' return an object
```

## failed attempts to solve

While the above is the main behavior I did not understand below the full list of attempts to handle `oDict.Keys` as array:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Function ArrayGet(ByRef aArray() As Variant, i As Integer) As Variant
    ArrayGet = aArray(i)
End Function

Public Function ArrayWrap(ByRef aArray() As Variant) As Variant()
    ArrayWrap = aArray
End Function

Public Sub TEST()

    Dim oDict As Object
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    oDict("key 1") = "value 1"
    oDict("key 2") = "value 2"
    oDict("key 3") = "value 3"

    Dim aKeys() As Variant
    aKeys = oDict.Keys

    Debug.Print VarType(aKeys)           ' prints "8204"
    Debug.Print VarType(oDict.Keys)      ' prints "8204"

    Debug.Print aKeys(2)                 ' prints "key 3"
    'Debug.Print oDict.Keys(2)            ' Run-time error '451': Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object
    'Debug.Print oDict.Keys.Get(2)        ' Run-time error '424': Object required
    'Debug.Print oDict.Keys.Item(2)       ' Run-time error '424': Object required

    Debug.Print ArrayGet(aKeys, 2)       ' prints "key 3"
    'Debug.Print ArrayGet(oDict.Keys, 2)  ' Compile error : Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected

    'Debug.Print Array(aKeys)(2)          ' Run-time error '9'  : Subscript out of range
    'Debug.Print Array(oDict.Keys)(2)     ' Run-time error '9'  : Subscript out of range

    Debug.Print ArrayWrap(aKeys)(2)      ' prints "key 3"
    'Debug.Print ArrayWrap(oDict.Keys)(2) ' Compile error : Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected

    Dim key As Variant

    For Each key In aKeys
        Debug.Print key                  ' prints "key 1", "key 2" and "key 3"
    Next key

    For Each key In oDict.Keys
        Debug.Print key                  ' prints "key 1", "key 2" and "key 3"
    Next key

End Sub
```

Comment: NOTE FROM OP: The process of writing the question actually allowed me to find the answer myself. Hopefully the keywords contained in this question allow somebody else to find the solution more quickly.

Comment: NOTE FROM OP: Now that the cause is known it is easy to see that it is the same root problem as [covered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47532267/2799887)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## what was wrong

```vb
    Debug.Print oDict.Keys(2)  ' Run-time error '451':
                               ' Property let procedure not defined 
                               ' and property get procedure did not 
                               ' return an object
```

The `Keys` word is a method. While VBA allows you to drop the parentheses when not providing arguments it is still a method. If you specify parentheses behind it the contents will be passed to the method. The `Keys` method does not accept an integer argument.

## how to fix

By explicitly providing the parentheses of the Keys method (like `Keys()`) we can directly apply / follow with the parentheses for accessing the array element.

In line with the example in the question: the following two alternatives are equivalent:

```vb
    Debug.Print aKeys(2)         ' prints "key 3"
    Debug.Print oDict.Keys()(2)  ' prints "key 3"
```

Comment: thank you for sharing your finding. This has been plaguing me for so many years...I usually check my dictionaries and dictionary of dictionaries in Immediate window and this is the best thing that happened to me today...OMG...Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't add the reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime, you need to use late binding to use a dictionary object. With late binding, you lose some functionality.

If you try to access the dictionary's keys by index, you will throw a runtime error 451.

> <sup>Run-time error '451':</sup>
> <sub>Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object.</sub>

[image]

If you add the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library reference to the project through the VBE's Tools, References you can now access the dictionary's keys directly through its ordinal index number.

[image]

```
Sub test3()

    Dim i As Long, dict As New Scripting.dictionary

    dict.Add Key:="key1", Item:="item1"
    dict.Add Key:="key2", Item:="item2"
    dict.Add Key:="key3", Item:="item3"

    For i = LBound(dict.Keys) To UBound(dict.Keys)
        Debug.Print dict.Keys(i)
    Next i

End Sub

'results
key1
key2
key3
```